# Serverless upload file to S3 cannot open

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to use serverless (Node.js) for file uploading

```
const contentType = event.headers['Content-Type'] || event.headers['content-type'];
const bb = new busboy({ headers: { 'content-type': contentType }});

// When file load
bb.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    console.log(fieldname, filename, encoding, mimetype);
    console.log(file);

    const key = 'upload/' + filename;
    var s3obj = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: 'fileupload',
            Key: key,
            ACL: 'public-read',
            ContentEncoding: encoding,
            ContentType: mimetype,
        }
    });

    s3obj.upload({ Body: file })
      .on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); })
      .send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });

})

bb.end(event.body);

callback(null, response({ status: 'success' }));
```

After ran this code S3 successfully created the file, but if I uploaded an image or other non-text files (not .txt, .csv), the file size will differ and the file cannot open.

May I know which part of my code goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that need to

`Add multipart/form-data binary media type`

under API gateway to get the correct encoding for the file.

I've followed this plugin

`https://github.com/myshenin/aws-lambda-multipart-parser`

to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when trying to upload an image. The solution was to enable the binary media types in the bucket settings.

I set the media types to `*/*`